# Сочетаемость слов

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать "это мероприятие **сообщит** участникам новую ***мотивацию***"?

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, мотивацию сообщить нельзя. Дать — можно.

Comment: это сочетание использовано по подобию "сообщит импульс" в значении - придаст, даст; а как передать длительный, а не одномоментный характер действия?

Answer (score 0):

---

Или "добавить".